# HTML Validation Error - No User-Agent header found

Tags: aptana

When I try to validate html syntax in Aptana I get the error "No User-Agent header found".  I have searched and found that this has been logged as a bug (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7773) but I am wondering if anyone has a workaround?

I am running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805 on a OSX platform.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Aptana Studio 3, Build 3.6.1.201410201044 on Windows and I had the same problem.  I was able to fix the problem by clicking on  then  and finally .  This made Aptana update all the bundles that are installed, correcting the validation problem.  Hope this helps.

B